# send invitation for user rails by adding user_id and page_id in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite3-ruby

I am new to rails and I have a task asking me to let a page admin to send invitations for regular users to be admins with him I implemented the part to reply to the invitations but I am stuck in an error and please tell me if I am on the right way  here is my code for the invitation method

```
def invite
  inviteUser = {"user_id" => current_user.id,"magazine_id" => params[:id]}
  CollaborationInvitation.create(inviteUser)
  @magazine = Magazine.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Here is my model for the invitation:

```
class CollaborationInvitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :magazine
end
```

Model for page:

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImgUploader
  has_many :articles
  acts_as_followable
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  errors[:image] << 'should be less than 5MB' if image.size > 5.megabytes

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :image, presence: true
  validate :image_size
end`
```

And the routes:

```
routes`member do
  put 'follow' => 'magazines#follow'
  put 'unfollow' => 'magazines#unfollow'
  put 'invite' => 'magazines#invite'
end
```

error : No route matches [GET] "/magazines/3/invite"
and when I changed the route from put to get

I get this error: `unknown attribute 'user_id' for CollaborationInvitation`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to setup the routes properly as resources. Remove the routes listed above and define these instead:

```
resources :magazines do
  member do
    put :follow
    put :unfollow
    put :invite
  end
end
```

Comment: I got the same error which is  No route matches [GET] "/magazines/3/invite"

Comment: Pass `method: :put` in your `link_to` or whatever you are using. It's defaulting to get, when you've explicitly said to require put.

Comment: I already have this in my link thats why I have no idea where is the problem

Comment: `<div class="row">
             <%if can? :invite, @magazine%>
                  <%=link_to'<span class="label label-primary" style="cursor: pointer">Invite</span>'.html_safe ,controller: :magazines,action: :invite, method: :put  %>
          <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="ID">
                    
              <%end%>`

Comment: Wrap `method: :put` in braces: `{method: :put}`, because its getting passed to the url_options and it should be passed to html_options.

Comment: actually it raised a new error which is  unknown attribute 'user_id' for CollaborationInvitation.  `  inviteUser = {"user_id" => current_user.id,"magazine_id" => params[:id]}
       CollaborationInvitation.create(inviteUser)
        @magazine =Magazine.find( params[:id])
     redirect_to :back
    end  ` which is in the magazine controller

Comment: Does the CollaborationInvitation model have a user_id column in the database?